# Show most requested URL in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, logging, performance-monitoring

Is there any way to show the most requested URL from apache over a timeframe, e.g. the most requested URL over the past 2 hours.

Is this type of thing possible with mod_status or could I aggregate the access logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found [apachetop](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=apachetop) which seems to do the job.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try [awstat](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)? It is log file analyzer tool. I am not sure if it can provide you with the stats within two hours as you requested.

You can also use a command like this to see the visited pages and its count within your log file.

```
$ awk {'print $7'} /var/log/apache2/access.log | sort | uniq -c
```

The timeframe will depend on the contents of the log file. You can combine this with other commands like `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 0):

goaccess is my favorite tool for this task https://goaccess.io/.

```
   WORKING WITH DATES
       Another useful pipe would be filtering dates out of the web log

       The following will get all HTTP requests starting on 05/Dec/2010 until the end of the file.

              # sed -n '/05Dec2010/,$ p' access.log | goaccess -a -

       or using relative dates such as yesterdays or tomorrows day:

              # sed -n '/'$(date '+%d%b%Y' -d '1 week ago')'/,$ p' access.log | goaccess -a -

       If we want to parse only a certain time-frame from DATE a to DATE b, we can do:

              # sed -n '/5Nov2010/,/5Dec2010/ p' access.log | goaccess -a -
```